# Xserver is working but not actually drawing on the screen

Tags: debian, x-server, bumblebee

I'm currently going through configuration hell with my xserver. I'm using nvidia's proprietary drivers and I believe I have everything set up properly:

- The Nouveau open source driver is blacklisted, and I can verify it hasn't been loaded by using `lsmod`;
- I've used nvidia-xconfig to generate an xorg.conf file, without wich X won't even start when I call `startx` or `X`;
- I've added `BusId   "PCI:1:0:0"` to the file generated though `nvidia-xconfig` , otherwise I get a "no devices found" error;
- I'm using Debian Jessie, so I also made sure that my alternatives make sense, that is, that the selected alternative for glx is the nvidia implementation.

I've put this in my `.xsession` file:

```
xterm
exit
```

so that when X starts I'm greeted by a blank screen with an xterm started at the top left corner. I am sure this .xsession file works because if I configure my system to use the Intel integrated GPU instead, everything works as expected, X starts and starts an xterm at the top left corner.

So when I finally run `startx` (with all that nvidia configuration mentioned before) my screen freezes as it is, with my last commands on the screen. The thing is, I KNOW that X is actually running. If I blindly take my mouse to the top left corner and click, I can get focus to the xterm window and from there run any command (blindly, of course). Once I type `exit` X exits and the screen can now update again.

I'd like to know why X isn't actually drawing to the screen.

Thanks o/

Comment: If you have an Itel Graphics Card you ned to have a look at the [Bumblebee Project](http://bumblebee-project.org/).  Please note that the NVIDIA Card in your machine is Discrete only, ie it cannot do the math to draw the display, it will only display pixels after the Intel card calculates.

Comment: Forgot to add: Here is the [Debian Wiki Entry on Bumblebee](https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee#Installation)